# reading only the daily julian values of a data given for every 3 hr

Tags: matlab

The data I am using is available per 3 hour time step. The Julian date for the data is therefore in an increasing order of 3/24 = 0.125 for each row of data value. I am interested only on the daily time step data and I would like to get help how to read only the daily Julian values that are recorded after every 8 Excel rows using Matlab.

Example of my data:

```
0.125
0.25
0.375
0.5
0.625
0.75
0.875
1
1.125
1.25
1.375
1.5
1.625
1.75
1.875
2
2.125
2.25
2.375
2.5
2.625
2.75
2.875
3
3.125
3.25
3.375
3.5
3.625
3.75
3.875
4
.
.
[continues until 360 and starts back from 0.125]
```

Comment: `out = data(1:8:end);`?

Comment: ow, that was such easy!

Comment: hahaha did it actually work?  Given your wording, that's what my best guess was in terms of what you required.